# Why are there clothes on the dining room chair?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I was digging out a new dining room and putting furniture in there, when I noticed someone had put his clothes on a chair. What could have caused this? There's enough bedrooms with chests for all dwarves.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i get this all the time randomly. people will just ditch some cloths in the hallway or the dining room.
maybe they just like the wind on there cheeks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the chosen answer from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12892/23609) you can see that your dwarves need a [cabinet](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Cabinet) to store their clothes, otherwise they're going to toss them around. Since clothes are owned it's very difficult to clean them up, so getting cabinets as soon as possible is a good idea.